# Mongoosejs use promise in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: question and answer. Each answer belongs to a question so an answer has its "question_id".

I like to get five questions which has most answers:

```
Answer.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$question_id',
                num_questions: { $sum: 1 },
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                'num_questions': -1
            }
        }
    ]).then(function(answers) {
        var result = [];
        for(answer of answers) {
            Question.findById(answer._id, function(err, question) {
                result.push(question);
            });
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.json({questions: result});
});
```

but with the above code, my result will be null because of the async mechanism.

How can I get it done ?

Another problem that I had, with the aggregate query, I can only have questions that has at least one answer. How can I get the questions without answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Answer.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$question_id',
                num_questions: { $sum: 1 },
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                'num_questions': -1
            }
        }
    ]).then(function(answers) {
        var result = [];
        var count = 0;
        for(answer of answers) {
            Question.findById(answer._id, function(err, question) {
         count++
                result.push(question);
       if (count == 5) {
        res.json({questions: result});
      }
            });
        }
        console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Your request returns only one question. How could i get five ? Thanks !

Comment: @Trong Lam Phan Edited for 5.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please help me with my second question ? About some questions that don't have any answer. How can i show them up ?

Comment: Guess: you're finding questions by searching for answer._id, so you must find your questions by searching for something else, because if the question has no answer there is no answer._id to find. But to tell you a A TRUTH instead of a GUESS you'd have to post the structure of your database and the rest of the code of your application.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I've found another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be using a Promise library like [**Q**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) which helps you with these things. With Q it's easy to wait until all promises resolve without using extra shenanigans (like using a count variable)..

```
Answer.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$question_id',
            num_questions: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            'num_questions': -1
        }
    }
]).then(function (answers) {
    var promises = [];
    for (answer of answers) {
        promises.push(Question.findById(answer._id).exec());
    }

    Q.all(promises).then(function(questions) {
        res.json({'questions': questions});
    });
});
```